# Attach Cloudinary image to Rails model using ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, cloudinary, rails-activestorage

I have a user model

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :photo
end
```

I'm trying to:

- upload an image to Cloudinary via URL (this works)
- attach it to a user instance which uses ActiveStorage (this does not)

Here is what I think should work

```rb
user_img_response = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload("https://www.formula1.com/content/dam/fom-website/manual/Misc/2019-Races/Monaco2019/Monaco%20chicane%20HAM%20VER%20sized.jpg.transform/9col/image.jpg")

img_id = user_img_response["url"].match(/image\/upload.*/)[0]
signature = "#{img_id}##{user_img_response["signature"]}"

preloaded_file = Cloudinary::PreloadedFile.new(signature)
user = User.new(title: "Chris")
user.photo = preloaded_file

user.save
=> true
```

However, the photo is not being attached to the user instance

```
user.photo.attached? 
=> false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your app/models/photo.rb looks similar to this:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :bytes, :image, :image_cache

  belongs_to :album

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validates_presence_of :title, :image
end
```

What happens if you try:

```
...
user = User.new(title: "Chris")
user.photo.image = preloaded_file # <---- assign file to image attribute
user.save
```

You can also try to emulate this sample app for your case: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/tree/master/samples/photo_album

**EDIT**: you can try something like this:

```
require 'uri'

file = URI.open(user_img_response["url"]) # use cloudinary url
photo.image.attach(io: file, filename: 'image.jpg')
```

See: https://blog.eq8.eu/til/upload-remote-file-from-url-with-activestorage-rails.html

Comment: Thanks for the response draganstankovic! It seems that this example uses CarrierWave, I should have mentioned that I'm using ActiveStorage (updated question). That's a great thought on assigning to the image attribute. That results in "*** Module::DelegationError Exception: image= delegated to attachment, but  attachment is nil",

Comment: Thanks for the follow up edit, @draganstankovic! If I use the cloudinary url it duplicates the image. Easy to fix if I use the original image url with File.open. Out of curiosity I'd still like to know if it's possible to upload to Cloudinary using the Cloudinary:: Uploader and attach to the model.

Comment: I would say by attaching the file directly like in the edit and specifying your active storage service to be Cloudinary (https://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_activestorage), saving the user will essentially trigger uploading using cloudinary properly.
If you're curious you can look at the source (upload is being done by the service): https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/blob/master/lib/active_storage/service/cloudinary_service.rb and see if you can extend it to suite your needs...